# Proper way to call a js function, onclick, inside a php echo string

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have these if statements that display sizes for a product. I want to change the css styling of the size when it's clicked so the user knows that one was clicked.

deep within my php script i have 3 if statements

```
echo " <script type='text/javascript' src='ryan.js'></script>";    
            if ($varGetProductArray1[4] > 0){
                    echo '  <div id ="sizeButton1"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(\'sizeButton1\',\'sizeButton2\',\'sizeButton3\')">      S </div> ' ;
            }

            if ($varGetProductArray1[5] > 0){

                    echo ' <div id ="sizeButton2"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(\'sizeButton2\',\'sizeButton1\',\'sizeButton3\')">      M </div> ';
            }
            if ($varGetProductArray1[6] > 0){

                    echo '          <div id ="sizeButton3"class="sizeButton" onclick="ryanClicked(\'sizeButton3\',\'sizeButton1\',\'sizeButton2\')">      L </div> ';
            }
```

there's the starting and ending php tags farther from the document.
then ryan.js just has a function

```
function ryanClicked(id, b, c,){
  b = b || null;
  c = c || null;
document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = "black";
document.getElementById(b).style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
document.getElementById(c).style.borderColor = "#e0e0e0";
}
```

if I don't include the if statements it works but i'm not sure why is it because the html loads before onclick function does? How could I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure of your $varGetProductArray1. If this is unset it will eval to  Undefined offset and not run the echo. If you had an else on your statement that would run.

Comment: You have a syntax error at `ryanClicked(id, b, c,){`. Trailing comma in the parameter list.

Comment: yes I'm sure of $varGetProductAray1  also the echo only happens if the statement is true so the buttons wouldnt even show if it wasn't right

Comment: yes that was it I didn't see it thanks treetree